# Where am I accessing illegal memory? realloc(): invalid next size

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, realloc

I'm making a shell simulator for an operating systems course homework.
We were asked to add a "history" command that when typed, should print a list of commands that the user entered.

I decided to implement it using a history array that allocates dynamically more memory depending on the size of the new command.

Here is my code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 100

//comment

int main(void)
{
    close(2);
    dup(1);
    char command[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char* hist = NULL;
    // int counter = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "my-shell> ");
        memset(command, '\0', BUFFER_SIZE);
        fgets(command, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
        if(strncmp(command, "exit", 4) == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        
        //alocate memory for the current position in the hist array
        if(hist == NULL){
            hist = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(command));
        }
        else{
            hist = realloc(hist,sizeof(char)*strlen(command));
        }
        strcat(hist,command);
        printf("the size of the boy: %d\n",(int) strlen(hist));
        // counter += strlen(command);

        int pid = fork();

        char *argv[BUFFER_SIZE];
        char *pch;

        pch = strtok(command, " \n");

        int i;
        for(i=0; pch != NULL; i++){
            argv[i] = pch;
            pch = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        }
        argv[i] = NULL;

        int hasAmpersand = 0;
        //check if the last entered character was '&'
        if(*argv[i-1]=='&'){
            // printf("entered &:");
            hasAmpersand = 1;
            //replace it with '\0'
            argv[i-1] = NULL;
        }
        
        if(pid == 0){ //child process execute sys call
            if(strncmp(argv[0],"history",7) == 0){
                printf("%s\n", hist);
                exit(1);
            }
            else{
                execvp(argv[0], argv);
                printf("\nbad syntax\n");
            }
        }
        else{
            if(!hasAmpersand){ //wait for child
                while(wait(NULL) != pid);
            }
        }
    }
    free(hist);

    return 0;
}
```

The implementation works for up to 6 commands stored in hist but it crashed with the error

```
realloc(): invalid next size
aborted
```

I was wondering what causes the issue and I'd love suggestions on fixing it. Thanks.

Comment: `strlen(command)` does not give you enough bytes to hold `command`. It does not account for the null terminator. So `strcat(hist, command);` writes off the end of the buffer. And that should be `strcpy` anyway, as `hist` is not initialized.

Comment: ohhhhh so I just need to add a +1 byte and everything will work out?

Comment: Possibly. I can't guarantee that's the only error.

Comment: Aside: you *can* call `realloc()` when `(hist == NULL)`, there is no special case to make in that regard, but as mentioned you must use `strcpy` then `strcat`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake @FredLarson

Comment: One other tip: `sizeof(char)` is 1 _by definition_, so multiplying by it is just clutter.

Comment: Notes: You don't need to zero-out `command` before using it in `fgets`. You don't need to use `strncmp` for comparing against fixed size strings, `strcmp` is fine. Instead of concatenating commands into a big string, consider using an array and `strdup`ing the commands; you will still need to grow the array, but it is a much more useful data structure, simpler to manage, and you can terminate it with a null.

Comment: Thank you guys for the support, every one of you added helpful comments and this was a really good experience asking a question! I cleaned up the code and it works like a charm (:

Comment: also... when you call `hist = realloc(hist,sizeof(char)*strlen(command));`, and the realloc fails, you have lost the data that `hist` previously pointed to. Better to save the result of `realloc` to a temporary variable and check it for null before proceeding.

Comment: @FredLarson: Personally, I think it is a good habit to write `sizeof(char)` anyway, even if it is not necessary. In my opinion, it makes the code clearer. Also, if you don't have the habit of writing it, then if you want to for example allocate memory for objects of type `int` instead, you can easily forget to multiply by `sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of realloc should be the new size of the entire block, not just the size of data you are "adding" to memory area.

hist = realloc(hist, currentHistSize + sizeof(char)*strlen(command));

Make sure you name currentHistSize as you want.

Answer (score 2):

You need room for the trailing string terminator `'\0'`, so add one to the allocated size:

```
hist = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(command) + 1);
```

The argument to *realloc* also needs to be adjusted. Also you probably want to remove the trailing newline after calling *fgets*.